# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a proxy crawler which stores data in sqlite database,and I prefer to saving a complex object by statement like  `cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))`
Then I find a useful official document [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#converting-sqlite-values-to-custom-python-types)
The example in official document works very well.
But there is a problem come to me.
I change the official code to :

```
import sqlite3
import time

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self,ip,port,speed,area,level,active,last_check_time):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.speed = speed
        self.area = area
        self.level = level
        self.active = active
        self.last_check_time = last_check_time
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%d;%d' % (self.ip,self.port,self.speed,self.area,self.level,self.active,self.last_check_time)



def adapt_proxy(proxy):
    return '%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%d;%d' % (proxy.ip,proxy.port,proxy.speed,proxy.area,proxy.level,proxy.active,proxy.last_check_time)

def convert_proxy(s):
    ip,port,speed,area,level,active,last_check_time = map(str, s.split(";"))
    return Proxy(ip,port,speed,area,level,int(active),int(last_check_time))


# Register the adapter
sqlite3.register_adapter(Proxy, adapt_proxy)

# Register the converter
sqlite3.register_converter("proxy", convert_proxy)

p = Proxy('231', '123', '2424','444','555',1,int(time.time()))

#########################
# 1) Using declared types
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table test(p proxy)")

cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))
cur.execute("select p from test")
print "with declared types:", cur.fetchone()[0]
cur.close()
con.close()

#######################
# 1) Using column names
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table test(p)")

cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))
cur.execute('select p as "p [proxy]" from test')
print "with column names:", cur.fetchone()[0]
cur.close()
con.close()
```

error occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\kss\Desktop\py\ts1.py", line 52, in <module>
    cur.execute("insert into test(p) values (?)", (p,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

It is really odd.I can not figure out it

Comment: You're missing the tuple parentheses on the `__repr__` formats.

Comment: @msw `__repr__` is just for output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your declaration of Proxy to:

```
class Proxy(object):
    # all the stuff before
```

The problem is that your class is not a "new style" class; inheriting from `object` makes it one.

Notice how the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#registering-an-adapter-callable) says:

> The type/class to adapt must be a new-style class, i. e. it must have
>   object as one of its bases.

Comment: Oh,that's it!I am too careless. Thank you very much!